# Compiling kernel modules on Debian 9

Tags: makefile, module, debian, kernel

I'm trying to build a kernel module under Debian 9.
I installed the necessary packages using

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-4.9.0-5-amd64
```

but I get the following error message when I try to compile my module:

```
> make
make -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-5-amd64/build M=/home/sven/tmp/kernel modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/4.9.0-5-amd64/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/4.9.0-5-amd64/build'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The problem seems to be that there is no Makefile in the

```
/lib/modules/4.9.0-5-amd64/build
```

directory. In fact, this directory is empty ...
This might be a beginner's question, but does anybody know how to fix this?
The source code for the kernel module as well as the corresponding Makefile are listed below.

Thank you very much for your help!

C Code for module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Homer S.");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("hmmmm ...");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0")


static int __init
start(void) {
  printk(KERN_INFO "\nCHELLAS!\n\n");
  return 0;
}


static void __exit
end(void) {
  printk(KERN_INFO "\nCIAO!\n\n");
  return 0;
}


module_init(start);
module_exit(end);
```

Makefile to compile the module:

```
obj-m+=foo.o

KVERSION=$(shell uname -r)

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Answer (score 0):

The makefile works fine with a more recent linux-headers package, it may have been a temporary issue or a problem with the package installation on your system.

Mind that your .c code would not compile tho:

```
diff --git a/foo.c b/foo.c
index 97611ef..5769fa7 100644
--- a/foo.c
+++ b/foo.c
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@
 MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
 MODULE_AUTHOR("Homer S.");
 MODULE_DESCRIPTION("hmmmm ...");
-MODULE_VERSION("1.0")
+MODULE_VERSION("1.0");


 static int __init
@@ -18,7 +18,6 @@ start(void) {
 static void __exit
 end(void) {
   printk(KERN_INFO "\nCIAO!\n\n");
-  return 0;
 }
```